# Table column widths disproportionate due to multicolumn cell being too long

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I'm trying to typeset a table that would have a header in the first row (I'm not looking for a different/better solution to adding a header, but for a fix to this solution. Thanks). I want to achieve this by **having a multicolumn cell spanning all the columns of the first row**. The problem is that if the text is too long, the **column widths are uneven**, with the last column accumulating excess width. I would expect all of the columns to be of *approximately* the same width (although I cannot find a decent source that would say they should), given the fact that all the text in the second row is of *approximately* the same width.

I find this behaviour quite puzzling and have no idea what the cause could be. I know I could perhaps remedy this by manually setting the column widths, but am curious as to how to fix this without doing that (**I do not need** or indeed want the **columns to be of the same width**, but roughly proportional to the length of their content), preferably but not necessarily by using the tabular environment only (some other conflict with the document class I am using).

What is it that I'm doing or assuming wrong? And why?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
\multicolumn{5}{c}{This is a piece of text. The longer it is, the longer the last column.} \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Resulting table. Notice how the last column of the second row accumulates excess width.

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's a feature of the `\halign` primitive:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}

\centering
\parskip2\baselineskip

\begin{tabular}{*5{c}}
\multicolumn{5}{c}{This is a piece of text. The longer it is, the longer the last column.} \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}


\begin{tabular}{*5{c}}
\multicolumn{5}{c}{\makebox[0pt]{This is a piece of text. The longer it is, the longer the last column.}} \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}


\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\textwidth minus\textwidth}}*5{c}@{}}
\multicolumn{5}{c}{This is a piece of text. The longer it is, the longer the last column.} \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
\hline
\end{tabular*}


\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{*{5}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}}
\multicolumn{5}{c}{This is a piece of text. The longer it is, the longer the last column.} \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}


\end{document}
```

Comment: So, `\halign` is the TeX primitive tabular is built on, right? I'll have to take a better look at it then. The `tabularx` example is close to what I want, but when I tried it in the real document (as opposed to the MWE), I found out it conflicts with the class that I have to use (or `supertabular`, which I use in several places). I've tried modifying the second-to-last example to look like the last, but to no avail. Ideas or a webpage that would explain this in a bit more detail? Thanks!

Comment: yes any latex thing that uses `&` is most likely using `\halign` somewhere. supertabular has a multipage version of tabular* so the version with extracolsep should work there.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle do you know if my solution can be done in one `tabularx` environment?

Answer (score 3):

Thank you so much David, this answer has helped me so much in using Excel2Latex.  I now use this in my preamble

```
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\newcommand{\deftab}[2]{\begin{tabularx}{#1}{*{#2}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}|}
```

and then use

```
\deftab{width}{no. of columns}
```

in place of the

```
\begin{tabular}
```

that Excel2Latex uses, and then I replace the necessary `\end{tabularx}` at the end of the table.  It automatically fixes all of these types of problems in tables of any size and does so without disrupting any formatting.

Answer (score 2):

I present a solution, where the size of the table fits its content:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\begin{document}


\newlength\widthSubTabOne
\settowidth\widthSubTabOne{This is a piece of text. The longer}
\newlength\lengthOne
\setlength\lengthOne{\dimexpr(\widthSubTabOne+2\tabcolsep)/5-2\tabcolsep\relax}

\newlength\widthSubTabTwo
\settowidth\widthSubTabTwo{it is, the longer the last column.}
\newlength\lengthTwo
\setlength\lengthTwo{\dimexpr(\widthSubTabTwo+2\tabcolsep)/2-2\tabcolsep\relax}


\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{title}
\begin{tabular}{*{5}{w{c}{\lengthOne}}*{2}{w{c}{\lengthTwo}}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{5}{c}{This is a piece of text. The longer} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{it is, the longer the last column.}\\
\cmidrule(r){1-5} \cmidrule(l){6-7}
a & b\tnote{$\ast$} & c & d & e & f & g\\
\midrule
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]
\setlength\labelsep{0pt}
\item long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long text
\end{tablenotes}
\begin{tablenotes}
\item [$\ast$] abc
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: you could simplify  by just using `\settowidth\widthSubTabOne{This is a piece of text. The longer}` and just adding 2\tabcolsep(+2\rulewidth)`

Answer (score 1):

The LaTeX3 package [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) has an option `hspan=even` for distributing extra space evenly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{
  colspec = {|c|c|c|c|c|},
  hspan = even, % distribute extra space evenly
  cell{1}{1} = {c=5}{c}, % multicolumn
}
\hline
This is a piece of text. The longer it is, the longer the last column. & & & & \\
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
\hline
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]