# Tabular column with equal width

Tags: tables, tabularx

I am trying make the width of the columns below `Very very long name` the same (G1 and G2).
The one on the top is created by using `tabular` and the other one is created with `tabularx`.
[image]
I have seen similar questions, but could not apply their solutions to my case.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5} % Default value: 1
    \begin{tabular}{lcccccc}
            \multicolumn{7}{c}{\textbf{ABC Metrics}} \\ \hline
            \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{Algorithm}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textit{Very very long name}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textit{Very very long name}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textit{Very very long name}} \\ \hline
            \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{Graph}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$G_1$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$G_2$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$G_1$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$G_2$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$G_1$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$G_2$} \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}}
\end{table}


\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XXXXXXX}
            \multicolumn{7}{c}{\textbf{ABC Metrics}} \\ \hline
            \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{Algorithm}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textit{Very very long name}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textit{Very very long name}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textit{Very very long name}} \\ \hline
            \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{Graph}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$G_1$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$G_2$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$G_1$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$G_2$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$G_1$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$G_2$} \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Related: [Table column widths disproportionate due to multicolumn cell being too long](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/95309/134144) Please also keep in mind, that using `\resizebox` in order to make a tabl fit into the textwidth leads to inconsistent font sizes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you load `geometry`, you'll have more sensible margins. The default is designed for marginal notes, so if you don't use them, you'll have more space on the line.

Note you shouldn't use `\resizebox` with tables, as it leads to inconsistent font sizes. Finally I don't see what all those `\multicolumn{1}{c|}` are in the code for, since you can centre the content of an `X` cell?

Here is a code with `X` cells:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]
    \centering
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5} % 
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|>{\hsize=1.72\hsize\bfseries\RaggedRight}X|*{6}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hsize=0.88\hsize}X|}}
            \multicolumn{7}{c}{\textbf{ABC Metrics}} \\[1ex] \hline
            \textbf{Algorithm}& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textit{Very very long name}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textit{Very very long name}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textit{Very very long name}} \\
            \hline%
            \textbf{Graph} & $G₁$ & $G₂$ & $G₁$ & $G₂$ & $G₁$ & $G₂$ \\ 
            \hline%
            \textbf{Weighted Ortho\-gonal Ordering} & $G₁$ & $G₂$ & $G₁$ & $G₂$ & $G₁$ & $G₂$ \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer. When one of the entries in a cell is too long this one still does not work (replace graph with "Weighted Orthogonal Ordering"). Resizing - inconsistent font size is not a problem for me, I just want the cells (G1 and G2) have the same size. 

I created the initial version of the table with an online table generator, those redundant `\multicolumn` comes from that tool.

Comment: @user3140972: I've posted another code, entirely based on the `X` columtype, using its capability to have different widths with `\hsize=xxx\hsize`.

Comment: thanks @Bernard I was able to get the desired result by setting the widths manually and decreasing the font size slightly.

Comment: Playing with the font size and the value of `\tabcolsep` are indeed two possibilities.

Answer (score 4):

A possible solution based on `tabularx` could be the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{Z}[1]{>{\Centering\arraybackslash\hsize=#1\hsize}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|}
  \multicolumn{7}{c}{\textbf{ABC Metrics}} \\ 
  \hline
  \textbf{Algorithm} & \multicolumn{2}{Z{2.3}|}{\textit{Very very long name}} & \multicolumn{2}{Z{2.3}|}{\textit{Very very long name}} & \multicolumn{2}{Z{2.3}|}{\textit{Very very long name}} \\ 
  \hline
  \textbf{Graph} & $G_1$  & $G_2$ & $G_1$ & $G_2$ & $G_1$ & $G_2$ \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In the above example, I have removed redundant `\multicolumn` commands. In order to horizontally center the contents of `X` columns, I have defined the new column type `Y`. For the multiolumns, I have replaced the `c` type columns by additionally defined `Z` type columns, that are based on `X` columns and therefor allow for automated linebreaks to make the table fit into the textwidth.

Comment: thanks. The linebreaks look ugly, especially when some lines are broken and other are not...

Comment: @user3140972, just increase text width of your page. than text in column headers will not be in two lines anymore.

Comment: @Zarko I can't really play with the geometry, this is a thesis template.

Comment: @user3140972, see my answer below. however, you should give us more accurate information about your page layout.

Comment: Hint: Load the `ragged2e` package and replace all `\centering` instructions with `\Centering`; the line lengths will be much more evenly distributed. Also, consider `2.3` instead of `2` as the argument of the `Z` columns. (Why? The usable width of a `Z` column is `2\hsize+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth` -- or ca `2.3\hsize`...)

Comment: @Mico: Thanks for reminding me. I have incorporated your suggestions in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

which table is more easy to read? the first? the second?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand\mcxit[1]{\multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep}C|}{\textit{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \tiny
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2} % Default value: 1
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|>{\bfseries}l|*{6}{C|}}
\multicolumn{7}{c}{\textbf{ABC Metrics}} \\[1ex] \hline
Algorithm   & \mcxit{Weighted Orthogonal Ordering}
            & \mcxit{Weighted Orthogonal Ordering}
            & \mcxit{Weighted Orthogonal Ordering}       \\
    \hline%
Graph       & $G_1$ & $G_2$ & $G_1$ & $G_2$ & $G_1$ & $G_2$ \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2} % Default value: 1
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|>{\bfseries}l|*{6}{C|}}
\multicolumn{7}{c}{\textbf{ABC Metrics}} \\[1ex] \hline
Algorithm   & \mcxit{Weighted Orthogonal Ordering}
            & \mcxit{Weighted Orthogonal Ordering}
            & \mcxit{Weighted Orthogonal Ordering}       \\
    \hline%
Graph       & $G_1$ & $G_2$ & $G_1$ & $G_2$ & $G_1$ & $G_2$ \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

in both cases, as you can see from mwe, are used your page layout (default for `article`). however, if you increase `\textwidth` with use of the package `geometry`, as suggested [Bernard](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/38908/bernard) in his answer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
% follows the same code as in mwe above
```

the table looks far better:

[image]

from above table images follows, that the second one is reasonable compromise.

**edit:**
one possible solution is to allow to table that it can spill-out from right text border. for example with use of the package `changepage`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand\mcxit[1]{\multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep}C|}{\textit{#1}}}

%-------------------------------------- only for show page layout
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.25pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{adjustwidth*}{0pt}{-\dimexpr\marginparsep+\marginparwidth}
    \small
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2} % Default value: 1
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|>{\bfseries}l|*{6}{C|}}
\multicolumn{7}{c}{\textbf{ABC Metrics}} \\[1ex] \hline
Algorithm   & \mcxit{Weighted Orthogonal Ordering}
            & \mcxit{Weighted Orthogonal Ordering}
            & \mcxit{Weighted Orthogonal Ordering}       \\
    \hline%
Graph       & $G_1$ & $G_2$ & $G_1$ & $G_2$ & $G_1$ & $G_2$ \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{adjustwidth*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

which still result with column headers text in two lines:

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout).