# Unexpected behavior with \multicolumn in \tabular

Tags: tables

I have a file with content akin to the following (which will be the base of my MWE) with the result shown:
[image: Desired]

Here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c c@{\hspace{0.5em}}c}
  Item & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Type} \\
  \midrule
  Thing 1 & babel & bottle \\
  Thing 2 & cable & cattle \\
  Thing 3 & fable & fiddle \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

This is exactly what I want. Unexpectedly, when I changed "Type" to something wider than the second and third columns, I obtained this result:
[image]

I expected the width between the second and third columns to remain the same, and that both would be centered under the header "Representations". I played around with a number of things, but I could not achieve that result.

Comment: Related: [Table column widths disproportionate due to multicolumn cell being too long](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/95309/134144)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose  increasing the last `\tabcolsep` and using `\makebox[0pt]`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c c@{\hspace{0.5em}}c@{\hspace{0.7em}}}
  Item & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\makebox[0em]{Representation}} \\
  \midrule
  Thing 1 & babel & bottle \\
  Thing 2 & cable & cattle \\
  Thing 3 & fable & fiddle \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This seems to work, thanks. Why did you increase the last `\tabcolsep`? Was is just for esthetics, or does it serve a role in the solution?

Comment: @Derek: Yes, it's for æsthetics – \tabcolsep was minimally increased, and  `@{\hspace{0.7em}}` was added, so that *Representation* doesn't go beyond the end of \midrule.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a proposal using nested `tabular`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c c}
  Item & Type \\
  \midrule
          \begin{tabular}{c}
            Thing 1\\
            Thing 2\\
            Thing 3\\
          \end{tabular}
           &
          \begin{tabular}{c c}
             babel & bottle \\
             cable & cattle \\
             fable & fiddle \\
        \end{tabular}
\end{tabular}

\vspace{0.5cm}
\begin{tabular}{c c}
  Item & Representation \\
  \midrule
          \begin{tabular}{c}
            Thing 1\\
            Thing 2\\
            Thing 3\\
          \end{tabular}
           &
          \begin{tabular}{c c}
             babel & bottle \\
             cable & cattle \\
             fable & fiddle \\
        \end{tabular}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is an interesting solution. Unfortunately in my case, my actual table is more complex, making the horizontal alignment too tricky for this solution.