# Multi-header column alignment with booktabs

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, booktabs

After looking at multiple tex.stackexchange questions, I'm still having trouble getting the alignment of multiple columns right.

Here's my code

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{}lcccc@{}}
    \toprule
        & \multicolumn{2}{@{}c}{Ignoring Unlabeled Detections} 
        & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{Approving Unlabeled Detections}\\
    \cmidrule(r){2-3} 
    \cmidrule(r){4-5}
        & Recall  & Precision    & Recall  & Precision  \\
    \cmidrule(r){2-3} 
    \cmidrule(r){4-5}
    % \midrule
    count           & 513     & 446         &  529     & 484     \\
    mean            & 0.428   & 0.787       &  0.507   & 0.841   \\
    std             & 0.343   & 0.365       &  0.337   & 0.310   \\
    min             & 0.000   & 0.000       &  0.000   & 0.000   \\
    \ensuremath{Q_1}& 0.000   & 0.667       &  0.286   & 0.800   \\
    \ensuremath{Q_2}& 0.500   & 1.000       &  0.500   & 1.000   \\
    \ensuremath{Q_3}& 0.667   & 1.000       &  0.750   & 1.000   \\
    max             & 1.000   & 1.000       &  1.000   & 1.000   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Which gives the result
[image: Result of code run]

I would naturally like the recall and precision columns to be equally spaced beneath each respective title.

Comment: The main issue is of course that the two column headers are wider than then two colums. Couldn't you drop the word "Detections" from them, and for example explain that in the caption to the table.

Comment: Of course, that is an option. But in my opinion, that is less readable, when there should exist a solution to align it the way I want.

Comment: I just tested your code, and I would actually be more extreme an and only use `Ignoring` and `Approving`, much less clutter for the reader to deal with. And I'd remove the `@{}` from those headers, looks strange.

Comment: Related: [Table column widths disproportionate due to multicolumn cell being too long](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/95309/134144)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a version that keeps the headers as they are and sets the column width of the second to fifth column with respect to the width of the corresponding multirow header.

However, I personally would prefer [Mico's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/482550/134144) as there are quite large white spaces in my version of the table.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{}l*{4}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\widthof{Approving Unlabeled Detections}/2 - 2\tabcolsep}}@{}}
    \toprule
        & \multicolumn{2}{@{}c}{Ignoring Unlabeled Detections} 
        & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{Approving Unlabeled Detections}\\
    \cmidrule(r){2-3} 
    \cmidrule(r){4-5}
        & Recall  & Precision    & Recall  & Precision  \\
    \cmidrule(r){2-3} 
    \cmidrule(r){4-5}
    % \midrule
    count           & 513     & 446         &  529     & 484     \\
    mean            & 0.428   & 0.787       &  0.507   & 0.841   \\
    std             & 0.343   & 0.365       &  0.337   & 0.310   \\
    min             & 0.000   & 0.000       &  0.000   & 0.000   \\
    $Q_1$           & 0.000   & 0.667       &  0.286   & 0.800   \\
    $Q_2$           & 0.500   & 1.000       &  0.500   & 1.000   \\
    $Q_3$           & 0.667   & 1.000       &  0.750   & 1.000   \\
    max             & 1.000   & 1.000       &  1.000   & 1.000   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

You could give the table header more visual structure, along the lines of the following example, by creating an additional line. You're of course entirely free to modify the proposed overall header, "Actions regarding unlabeled detections".

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{@{} l cccc @{}}
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{4}{c@{}}{Actions regarding unlabeled detections}\\
    \cmidrule(l){2-5}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Ignore} & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{Approve}\\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(l){4-5}
    & Recall & Precision & Recall & Precision  \\
    \midrule
    count & 513     & 446         &  529     & 484     \\
    \addlinespace
    mean  & 0.428   & 0.787       &  0.507   & 0.841   \\
    std   & 0.343   & 0.365       &  0.337   & 0.310   \\
    \addlinespace
    min   & 0.000   & 0.000       &  0.000   & 0.000   \\
    $Q_1$ & 0.000   & 0.667       &  0.286   & 0.800   \\
    $Q_2$ & 0.500   & 1.000       &  0.500   & 1.000   \\
    $Q_3$ & 0.667   & 1.000       &  0.750   & 1.000   \\
    max   & 1.000   & 1.000       &  1.000   & 1.000   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note also the use of two `\addlinespace` instructions to provide some visual grouping inside the body of the table.