# How to put math symbol rotated with 90 degree in table cell?

Tags: tables, symbols

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,multirow,booktabs}
\begin{document}   
 \begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{@{}ccccccccc@{}}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{7}{c}{\bfseries COLUMN}\\
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \textbf{x} & & \textbf{y} & & \textbf{z} && x\\
    \multirow{3}{*}{\bfseries ROW} & \textbf{p} & 6 &$>$& 4 &$<$& 5 &$<$&6\\
     & \textbf{q} & 5 &$<$& 16 &$>$& 5 &=& 5\\
     & \textbf{r} & 2 &$<$& 4 &$>$& -7 &$<$& 2\\
     \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Strategies}
    \label{tab:dominantColumn}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I want to do this type of comparison for row wise also. How can I put the symbol (90 degree shifted needed). `>` changed to `v` and `<` change to `^`.

I need to something like this.

```
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}ccccc@{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\bfseries COLUMN}\\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \textbf{x} & \textbf{y} & \textbf{z}\\
\multirow{4}{*}{\bfseries ROW} & \textbf{p} & 6 & 4 & 5\\
&&&&\\%here the symbo
 & \textbf{q} & 5 & 16 & 5\\
 &&&&\\%here the symbo
 & \textbf{r} & 2 & 4 & -7\\
 &&&&\\%here the symbol
 & \textbf{p} & 6 & 4 & 5\\
 \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Strategies}
\label{tab:dominantRow}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\rotatebox` from `graphicx` can do it for you. Here I only add one "`^`" and one "`v`". To make the symbol accurately centered, you may need option `origin=c`, as suggested by [@leandriis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/134144/leandriis) [in his comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/483487/how-to-put-math-symbol-rotated-with-90-degree-in-table-cell/483490?noredirect=1#comment1222346_483490).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand\downsym{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$<$}}
\newcommand\upsym{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$>$}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}ccccc@{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\bfseries COLUMN}\\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \textbf{x} & \textbf{y} & \textbf{z}\\
\multirow{4}{*}{\bfseries ROW} & \textbf{p} & 6 & 4 & 5\\
&&&&\\%here the symbo
 & \textbf{q} & 5 & 16 & 5\\
 &\downsym&&&\\%here the symbo
 & \textbf{r} & 2 & 4 & -7\\
 &&&\upsym&\\%here the symbol
 & \textbf{p} & 6 & 4 & 5\\
 \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Strategies}
\label{tab:dominantRow}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As you might have noticed, the rotated symbols are not vertically centered (especially the `\downsym`). To overcome this you might want to add the option `origin=c` as in `\newcommand\downsym{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$<$}}`

Comment: @leandriis Thanks for pointing that out! I did not even observe it. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a different approach using the symbols `\vee` and `\wedge`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow,booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}ccccc@{}}
\toprule
& & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\bfseries COLUMN}\\
& & \textbf{x} & \textbf{y} & \textbf{z}\\
\multirow{7}{*}{\bfseries ROW} & \textbf{p} & 6 & 4 & 5\\
&&$\vee$&$\wedge$&\\%here the symbo
 & \textbf{q} & 5 & 16 & 5\\
 &&&&\\%here the symbo
 & \textbf{r} & 2 & 4 & -7\\
 &&&&\\%here the symbol
 & \textbf{p} & 6 & 4 & 5\\
 \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Strategies}
\label{tab:dominantRow}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Please note, that I have changed `\multirow{4}` to `\multirow{7}` in order to vertically center `ROW`. You might also want to keep in mind that the z column is wider than the x and y column. This is because the fcolumn header is wider than the combined width of the three columns. If you want to get rid of this, you might be interested in [Table column widths disproportionate due to multicolumn cell being too long](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/95309/134144)

Comment: You might want to consider using a real (math) minus for the `-7` entry.  Right now, it's a hyphen, and looks too narrow.