# Centering a batch of columns with respect to larger multicolumn cell above them

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, tabularx

[image]

In the table above, the three columns below the multicolumn are smaller and are aligned to the left. However, I want them to be vertically centered with respect to the largest multicolumn above them as follows

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

    \usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

    \usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}

        \geometry{twoside=true, showframe=false}

        % Horizontal
        \geometry{inner=5mm, outer=5mm, includemp=true, bindingoffset=5mm, marginparsep=3.5mm, marginparwidth=15mm}

        % Vertical
        \geometry{top=20mm, vmarginratio=3:5, includehead=true, includefoot=true, headheight=8pt, headsep=14pt, footskip=5mm}

    \usepackage{ragged2e}


    \usepackage{tabularx}

        \newcolumntype{C}{ >{\arraybackslash \Centering}X }

    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{makecell}

    \usepackage{mathtools}



\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[htb]

    % Center the table
    \centering

    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{*{3}{l} >{\hsize=0.75\hsize}C !{\vrule width 0.25mm}*{3}{l} >{\hsize=0.75\hsize}C !{\vrule width 0.25mm}>{\hsize=1.5\hsize}C}

        \toprule

        \multicolumn{3}{c}{Exhaustive Search Method} & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Proposed Method} & &
        \\
        \Xhline{0.25mm}

        \multicolumn{3}{c}{Combination of POIs} & $\mathit{SDSCR_{min}}$ & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Combination of POIs} & $\mathit{SDSCR_{min}}$ & Reference POIs
        \\
        \Xhline{0.25mm}

        33 & 36 & 35 & 4.90 & 33 & 36 & 35 & 4.90 & 36
        \\

        34 & 33 & 35 & 5.23 & 34 & 33 & 35 & 5.23 & 34
        \\

        11 & 5 & 31 & 5.63 & 11 & 5 & 31 & 5.63 & 11
        \\

        33 & 14 & 35 & 5.73 & 33 & 14 & 35 & 5.73 & 31
        \\

        14 & 5 & 31 & 5.76 & 14 & 5 & 31 & 5.76 & 14
        \\
        \Xhline{0.25mm}

        \multicolumn{3}{c}{\color{DodgerBlue2} \bfseries Time 8.8 s} & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\color{DodgerBlue2} \bfseries Time 0.46 s} & &
        \\

        \bottomrule


    \end{tabularx}

\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Probably interesting: [Table column widths disproportionate due to multicolumn cell being too long](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/95309/134144)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage[a4paper,twoside]{geometry}
\geometry{inner=5mm, outer=5mm, includemp=true,
          bindingoffset=5mm, marginparsep=3.5mm, 
          marginparwidth=15mm,
          top=20mm, vmarginratio=3:5, includeheadfoot, 
          headheight=8pt, headsep=14pt, footskip=5mm}

\usepackage{ragged2e,tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{ >{\arraybackslash\Centering}X }
\usepackage{booktabs,makecell,mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} 
   *{2}{*{3}{>{\hsize=0.9\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}C} 
             >{\hsize=1.3\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}C} 
   c @{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{4}{@{}c}{Exhaustive Search Method}  & 
\multicolumn{4}{c}{Proposed Method} & 
Reference POIs\\
\cmidrule(r){1-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-8}
\multicolumn{3}{@{}c}{Combination of POIs} & $\mathit{SDSCR}_{\min}$ & 
\multicolumn{3}{c}{Combination of POIs} & $\mathit{SDSCR}_{\min}$ & \\
\cmidrule(r){1-3}  \cmidrule(lr){4-4}
\cmidrule(lr){5-7} \cmidrule(lr){8-8}
\cmidrule(l){9-9}
33 & 36 & 35 & 4.90 & 33 & 36 & 35 & 4.90 & 36 \\
34 & 33 & 35 & 5.23 & 34 & 33 & 35 & 5.23 & 34 \\
11 &  5 & 31 & 5.63 & 11 &  5 & 31 & 5.63 & 11 \\
33 & 14 & 35 & 5.73 & 33 & 14 & 35 & 5.73 & 31 \\
14 &  5 & 31 & 5.76 & 14 &  5 & 31 & 5.76 & 14 \\
\cmidrule(r){1-3} \cmidrule(lr){5-7}
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\color{DodgerBlue2}\bfseries Time 8.8\,s} & & 
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\color{DodgerBlue2}\bfseries Time 0.46\,s} & & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're quite lucky with this table: setting the long header at zero width solves the issue.

I'd avoid vertical rules altogether and use `siunitx` for better alignment of the figures.

```latex
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\geometry{
  % General
  twoside=true,
  showframe=false,
  % Horizontal
  inner=5mm,
  outer=5mm,
  includemp=true,
  bindingoffset=5mm,
  marginparsep=3.5mm,
  marginparwidth=15mm,
  % Vertical
  top=20mm,
  vmarginratio=3:5,
  includehead=true,
  includefoot=true,
  headheight=8pt,
  headsep=14pt,
  footskip=5mm,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb]

% Center the table
\centering

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  S[table-format=2.0]
  S[table-format=2.0]
  S[table-format=2.0]
  S[table-format=1.2]
  S[table-format=2.0]
  S[table-format=2.0]
  S[table-format=2.0]
  S[table-format=1.2]
  S[table-format=2.0]
  @{}
}
\toprule

\multicolumn{4}{@{}c}{Exhaustive Search Method} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Proposed Method} \\
\cmidrule(r){1-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-8}
\multicolumn{3}{@{}c}{\makebox[0pt]{Combination of POIs}} & $\mathit{SDSCR}_{\min}$ &
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\makebox[0pt]{Combination of POIs}} & $\mathit{SDSCR}_{\min}$ &
{Reference POIs} \\
\midrule

33 & 36 & 35 & 4.90 & 33 & 36 & 35 & 4.90 & 36 \\
34 & 33 & 35 & 5.23 & 34 & 33 & 35 & 5.23 & 34 \\
11 &  5 & 31 & 5.63 & 11 &  5 & 31 & 5.63 & 11 \\
33 & 14 & 35 & 5.73 & 33 & 14 & 35 & 5.73 & 31 \\
14 &  5 & 31 & 5.76 & 14 &  5 & 31 & 5.76 & 14 \\
\midrule

\multicolumn{3}{@{}c}{\color{DodgerBlue2}\bfseries Time \SI{8.8}{s}} &&
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\color{DodgerBlue2}\bfseries Time \SI{0.46}{s}} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since the culprit is the length of the `multicolumn` headers, I'd simply abbreviate these and mention the full description in the caption text. Thus, a simple tabular could be used with standard alignments `r`, `c`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{twoside=true, showframe=false}

% Horizontal
\geometry{inner=5mm, outer=5mm, includemp=true, bindingoffset=5mm, marginparsep=3.5mm, marginparwidth=15mm}

% Vertical
\geometry{top=20mm, vmarginratio=3:5, includehead=true, includefoot=true, headheight=8pt, headsep=14pt, footskip=5mm}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[htb]
    % Center the table
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{*3{r}c*3{r}cc}
        \toprule
        \multicolumn{4}{c}{Exhaustive Search Method} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Proposed Method} & \\
        \cmidrule(r){1-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-8}
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{Comb.\ POIs} & $\mathit{SDSCR_{\min}}$ & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Comb.\ POIs} & $\mathit{SDSCR_{\min}}$ & Ref.\ POIs        \\  \midrule
        33 & 36 & 35 & 4.90 & 33 & 36 & 35 & 4.90 & 36 \\
        34 & 33 & 35 & 5.23 & 34 & 33 & 35 & 5.23 & 34 \\
        11 & 5  & 31 & 5.63 & 11 & 5  & 31 & 5.63 & 11 \\
        33 & 14 & 35 & 5.73 & 33 & 14 & 35 & 5.73 & 31 \\
        14 & 5  & 31 & 5.76 & 14 & 5 & 31 & 5.76 & 14  \\ \midrule
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{\color{DodgerBlue2} \bfseries Time 8.8 s} & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\color{DodgerBlue2} \bfseries Time 0.46 s} & & \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

> [image]