# Tabular make widths equal

Tags: tables

I am using the tabular method to create my table. However, I notice that the widths of the columns are not equal like in the figure below. How do I make them equal ?

[image]

```
\begin{table}\centering
\begin{tabular}{l c c c c c c c c c c}
\toprule
    & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Evaluate on complete ground truth} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Evaluate on truncated} \\ 
    \cmidrule(l{2pt}r{2pt}){2-6} \cmidrule(l{2pt}r{2pt}){7-11}
    & 0s & 1s & 2s & 3s & 4s & 0s & 1s & 2s & 3s & 4s \\
    \midrule
Multi-Task Net & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 0s & 1s & 2s & 3s & 4s \\
CNN & 71.3 & & & & & & 23.9 & 30.3 & & \\
Keypoints & 55.6 & & & & & & 10.0 & 15.2 & & \\
JAAD & 68.3 & & & & & & 18.3 & 24.9 & & \\
\midrule
CNN LSTM & 68.3 & & & & & & 18.3 & 24.9 & & \\
Keypoints LSTM & 68.3 & & & & & & 18.3 & 24.9 & & \\
3D CNN & 68.3 & & & & & & 18.3 & 24.9 & & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Foo matter}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Related and most likely worth having a look at: [Table column widths disproportionate due to multicolumn cell being too long](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/95309/134144)

Comment: Could you please state the connection to the `tabularx` and `tabulary` packages? You don't seem to use them in your code.

Comment: @leandriis there is no tabular package in the list of tags

Comment: I've edited the tags and used `tables` instead. (From the tag description: {tables} is about the tabular environment and related packages [...])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution with `tabularx`, adding an empty column between the groups of 5 `X` columns to make the separation clearer:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
    \usepackage{geometry}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{table}\centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}l *{5}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} c *{5}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} }
    \toprule
        & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Evaluate on complete ground truth} & & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Evaluate on truncated} \\
        \cmidrule(l{2pt}r{2pt}){2-6} \cmidrule(l{2pt}r{2pt}){8-12}
        & 0s & 1s & 2s & 3s & 4s & & 0s & 1s & 2s & 3s & 4s \\
        \midrule
    Multi-Task Net & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & & 0s & 1s & 2s & 3s & 4s \\
    CNN & 71.3 & & & & & & & 23.9 & 30.3 & & \\
    Keypoints & 55.6 & & & & & & & 10.0 & 15.2 & & \\
    JAAD & 68.3 & & & & & & & 18.3 & 24.9 & & \\
    \midrule
    CNN LSTM & 68.3 & & & & & & & 18.3 & 24.9 & & \\
    Keypoints LSTM & 68.3 & & & & & & & 18.3 & 24.9 & & \\
    3D CNN & 68.3 & & & & & & & 18.3 & 24.9 & & \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \caption{Foo matter}
    \end{table}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

In order to make the five columns equally wide, you have several options. The following MWE includes two of them. In both examples, I made the text in the multicolumn narrower by using a linebreak or by adding another shared column header.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}\centering
\begin{tabular}{l c c c c c c c c c c}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{5}{c}{Evaluate on}\\
    & \multicolumn{5}{c}{complete ground truth} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Evaluate on truncated} \\ 
    \cmidrule(l{2pt}r{2pt}){2-6} \cmidrule(l{2pt}r{2pt}){7-11}
    & 0s & 1s & 2s & 3s & 4s & 0s & 1s & 2s & 3s & 4s \\
    \midrule
Multi-Task Net & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 0s & 1s & 2s & 3s & 4s \\
CNN & 71.3 & & & & & & 23.9 & 30.3 & & \\
Keypoints & 55.6 & & & & & & 10.0 & 15.2 & & \\
JAAD & 68.3 & & & & & & 18.3 & 24.9 & & \\
\midrule
CNN LSTM & 68.3 & & & & & & 18.3 & 24.9 & & \\
Keypoints LSTM & 68.3 & & & & & & 18.3 & 24.9 & & \\
3D CNN & 68.3 & & & & & & 18.3 & 24.9 & & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Foo matter}
\end{table}


\begin{table}\centering
\begin{tabular}{l c c c c c c c c c c}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{10}{c}{Evaluate on}\\ \cmidrule(l{2pt}r{2pt}){2-11}
    & \multicolumn{5}{c}{complete ground truth} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{truncated} \\ 
    \cmidrule(l{2pt}r{2pt}){2-6} \cmidrule(l{2pt}r{2pt}){7-11}
    & 0s & 1s & 2s & 3s & 4s & 0s & 1s & 2s & 3s & 4s \\
    \midrule
Multi-Task Net & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 0s & 1s & 2s & 3s & 4s \\
CNN & 71.3 & & & & & & 23.9 & 30.3 & & \\
Keypoints & 55.6 & & & & & & 10.0 & 15.2 & & \\
JAAD & 68.3 & & & & & & 18.3 & 24.9 & & \\
\midrule
CNN LSTM & 68.3 & & & & & & 18.3 & 24.9 & & \\
Keypoints LSTM & 68.3 & & & & & & 18.3 & 24.9 & & \\
3D CNN & 68.3 & & & & & & 18.3 & 24.9 & & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Foo matter}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much. But I ended up using Bernard's solution. Much easier to modify that for my other tables.

Answer (score 2):

A solution using the package [cals](https://ctan.org/pkg/cals):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}             % Article class from KOMA-script
\usepackage{cals}

% Defining shortcuts reduces typing

\let\nc=\nullcell
\let\sc=\spancontent

\makeatletter
\def\tb{\ifx\cals@borderT\relax     % Top border switch (off-on)
    \def\cals@borderT{0pt}
\else \let\cals@borderT\relax\fi}

\def\bb{\ifx\cals@borderB\relax     % Botton border switch (off-on)
    \def\cals@borderB{0pt}
\else \let\cals@borderB\relax\fi}

\def\rb{\ifx\cals@borderR\relax     % Right border switch (off-on)
    \def\cals@borderR{0pt}
\else \let\cals@borderR\relax\fi}

\def\lp{\ifdim\cals@paddingL=0.0pt\relax    % Left padding switch (off-on)
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
\else \setlength{\cals@paddingL}{0pt}\fi}

\def\rp{\ifdim\cals@paddingR=0.0pt\relax    % Left padding switch (off-on)
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
\else \setlength{\cals@paddingR}{0pt}\fi}


\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{table}\centering
\captionabove{Foo matter}       % KOMA-script internal
\small
\begin{calstable}

\colwidths{{\dimexpr(\columnwidth/30*8)\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth/30*2)\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth/30*2)\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth/30*2)\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth/30*2)\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth/30*2)\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth/30*2)\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth/30*2)\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth/30*2)\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth/30*2)\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth/30*2)\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth/30*2)\relax}
        }

% Set up the tabular
\makeatletter
\def\cals@framers@width{0.6pt} % Horizontal frame rule  
\def\cals@framecs@width{0pt}   % No vertical frame rule 
\def\cals@bodyrs@width{0.6pt}  % Rule between heading and body
\cals@setpadding{Ag}           % Column separation
\cals@setcellprevdepth{Al}
\def\cals@cs@width{0pt}        % No vertical rules 
\def\cals@rs@width{0.4pt}      % Horizontal rules

% R1 H1
\thead{
\brow
    \lp\cell{}\lp              % Remove tabular left side bearing 
    \nc{ltb}                   % Spanning cells (multicol and multirow equivalent
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \lp\rp\nc{rtb}\alignC\sc{\vfill Evaluate on\\ complete ground truth\strut}\lp
    \cell{}
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \rp\nc{rtb}\alignC\sc{\vfill Evaluate on truncated\strut}\rp %% Remove tabular right side bearing
\erow
% R2 H2
\brow
    \lp\tb\cell{}\tb\lp
    \alignR\cell{0s}
    \cell{1s}
    \cell{2s}
    \cell{3s}
    \cell{4s}
    \tb\cell{}\tb
    \lp\alignR\cell{0s}
    \cell{1s}
    \cell{2s}
    \cell{3s}
    \rp\cell{4s}\rp
\erow
}
% R3 B1
\brow
    \lp\alignL\cell{Multi-Task Net}\lp
    \alignR\cell{0}
    \cell{1}
    \cell{2}
    \cell{3}
    \cell{4}
    \cell{}
    \cell{0s}
    \cell{1s}
    \cell{2s}
    \cell{3s}
    \rp\cell{4s}\rp
\erow
% R4 B2
\brow
    \lp\tb\alignL\cell{CNN}\lp
    \alignR\cell{71.3}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{23.9}
    \cell{30.3}
    \cell{}
    \rp\cell{}\rp
\erow
% R5 B3
\brow  
    \lp\alignL\cell{Keypoints}\lp
    \alignR\cell{55.6}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{10.0}
    \cell{15.2}
    \cell{}
    \rp\cell{}\rp
\erow
% R6 B4
\brow
    \lp\alignL\cell{JAAD}\lp
    \alignR\cell{68.3}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{18.3 }
    \cell{24.9}
    \cell{}
    \rp\cell{}\rp
\erow
% R7 B5
\brow
    \lp\alignL\cell{}\lp
    \alignR\cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \rp\cell{}\rp
\erow
% R8 B6
\brow
    \lp\alignL\cell{CNN LSTM}\lp
    \alignR\cell{68.3}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{18.3}
    \cell{24.9}
    \cell{}
    \rp\cell{}\rp
\erow
% R9 B7
\brow
    \lp\alignL\cell{Keypoints LSTM}\lp
    \alignR\cell{68.3}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{18.3}
    \cell{24.9}
    \cell{}
    \rp\cell{}\rp
\erow
% % R10 B8
\brow
    \lp\alignL\cell{3D CNN}\lp
    \alignR\cell{68.3}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{18.3}
    \cell{24.9}
    \cell{}
    \rp\cell{}\rp
\erow
\makeatother
\end{calstable}\par
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]