# Adjusting Table in Latex tabularx environment

Tags: tables, tabularx, cline

I am having difficult time with adjusting the following table. I have the code as follows:

```
\documentclass[dissertation,letterpaper,12pt]{utthesis}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackages{multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[hb]
  \centering
  \footnotesize
  \caption{Parameter settings and results for different scenarios. \label[tab]{results}}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{c@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lcccccccccccc}
  \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Part\\ Type \#\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{12}{c}{$\mu_j=U(91,876)$}\\ \cline{2-13}
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{$\lambda_j=U(0.01,0.1)$} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$\lambda_j=U(0.09,0.1)$} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$\lambda_j=U(0.1,0.5)$} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$\lambda_j=U(0.5,0.9)$} \\ \cline{2-13}
& \multicolumn{12}{c}{Planning Horizon (Years)}\\ \cline{2-13}
& 10& 20& 30& 10& 20& 30& 10& 20& 30& 10& 20& 30\\ \hline
1& I& I& A& I& A& I& A& I& A& A& I& A\\
2& I& I& A& I& I& A& I& I& A& A& A& A\\
3& I& I& I& I& A& A& A& A& I& I& I& I\\
4& I& I& I& I& A& A& I& A& I& I& A& I\\
5& I& P& P& I& I& P& A& I& P& P& P& A\\
6& I& A& A& I& I& A& A& I& A& I& A& I\\ \hline     
\end{tabularx}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

I am using the tabularx environment because it easily allows placing the textwidth. However, it does not always nicely fill it. For example, the above code produces something like:

[image]

I have two problems in this result. The first one is I want equal cell  width for each 10,20,30 columns. The second one is `cline` does not fill the whole text (not equal to \textwidth). Any quick solutions?

Comment: Where did you get `utthesis.cls` from?

Comment: Please also clarify what `\label[tab]{results}`is supposed to do.

Comment: You're using `tabularx` but you have no `X` columns in your table. What do you expect it to do?

Comment: @AlanMunn - I suspecdt the OP is actually using a `tabular*` rather than a `tabularx` environment.

Comment: The column widths in your table appear to be disproportionate because the `\multicolumn` entries are longer than the combined widths of the three corresponding columns. For more information see here: [Table column widths disproportionate due to multicolumn cell being too long](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/95309/134144). Probably you could introduce linebreaks in the column headers to circumvent this problem. I'd also recommend that you take a look at the horizontal lines from the `booktabs` package.

Comment: @leandriis utthesis.cls comes from [here](https://gradschool.utk.edu/thesesdissertations/formatting/templates/). `\label[tab]{results}` just defines label for cleveref.

Comment: @Mico I'm using tabularx.

Comment: @user8028576 - In that case, `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` doesn't belong in the picture at all. You should be using suitably modified versions of the `X` column type instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**NB!** *I Corrected the `\label[tab]{results}`, which is wrong syntax unless your thesis-package redefines the `label`-command. However, I really recommend you to have a look at [cleveref](https://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref).*

Use tabular `X`-column since you are using [tabularx](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx). In addition, I used a fixed width column as first column using [array](https://ctan.org/pkg/array)’s `w`-column (require an updated version of array). Also, use [booktabs](https://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) rules instead of `hline` and `cline` to have better spacing between the rows. If you prefer more space between row 2 and row 3, use `\addlinespace` from [booktabs](https://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs):

**Example 1**

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx, booktabs, array, caption}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
  \centering
  \footnotesize
  \caption{Parameter settings and results for different scenarios.
  \label{tab:results}}  %%%%  <------- Corrected
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}>{\raggedright}wl{1.5cm}*{12}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}@{}}
  \toprule
\multirow{5}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Part\\ Type \#\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{12}{c}{$\mu_j=U(91,876)$}\\ \cmidrule{2-13}
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{$\lambda_j=U(0.01,0.1)$} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$\lambda_j=U(0.09,0.1)$} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$\lambda_j=U(0.1,0.5)$} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$\lambda_j=U(0.5,0.9)$} \\ \cmidrule{2-13}
& \multicolumn{12}{c}{Planning Horizon (Years)}\\ \cmidrule{2-13}
& 10& 20& 30& 10& 20& 30& 10& 20& 30& 10& 20& 30\\ \midrule
1& I& I& A& I& A& I& A& I& A& A& I& A\\
2& I& I& A& I& I& A& I& I& A& A& A& A\\
3& I& I& I& I& A& A& A& A& I& I& I& I\\
4& I& I& I& I& A& A& I& A& I& I& A& I\\
5& I& P& P& I& I& P& A& I& P& P& P& A\\
6& I& A& A& I& I& A& A& I& A& I& A& I\\ \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

**Example 2**

This is with split `cmidrule` and `!{\hspace*{0.25em}}` to increase space between column 4 and 5, 7 and 8 and 10 and 11 to group columns. In addition, I used `\addlinespace` to increase space between row 2 and 3.

It is the `(l)` statement in `\cmidrule(l){2-4}` that split the rule. Just remove the parenthesis and their content to have a solid rule.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx, booktabs, array, caption}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}


\begin{table*}
  \centering
  \footnotesize
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.4em}
  \caption{Parameter settings and results for different scenarios.
  \label{tab:results}}  %%%%  <------- Corrected
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}>{\raggedright}
                             wl{1.5cm}*{3}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
                             !{\hspace*{0.25em}}*{3}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
                             !{\hspace*{0.25em}}*{3}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
                             !{\hspace*{0.25em}}*{3}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
                             @{}
            }
\toprule
\multirow{6}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Part\\ Type \#\end{tabular}}
& \multicolumn{12}{c}{$\mu_j=U(91,876)$}\\
\cmidrule(l){2-13}
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{$\lambda_j=U(0.01,0.1)$} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$\lambda_j=U(0.09,0.1)$}
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{$\lambda_j=U(0.1,0.5)$} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$\lambda_j=U(0.5,0.9)$} \\ 
\cmidrule(lr{\tabcolsep}){2-4}\cmidrule(lr{\tabcolsep}){5-7}
\cmidrule(lr{\tabcolsep}){8-10}\cmidrule(l){11-13}
\addlinespace[3pt]
& \multicolumn{12}{c}{Planning Horizon (Years)}\\ \cmidrule(l){2-13}
& 10& 20& 30& 10& 20& 30& 10& 20& 30& 10& 20& 30\\ \midrule
1& I& I& A& I& A& I& A& I& A& A& I& A\\
2& I& I& A& I& I& A& I& I& A& A& A& A\\
3& I& I& I& I& A& A& A& A& I& I& I& I\\
4& I& I& I& I& A& A& I& A& I& I& A& I\\
5& I& P& P& I& I& P& A& I& P& P& P& A\\
6& I& A& A& I& I& A& A& I& A& I& A& I\\ \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: At least of second `\cmidrule{2-13}` I would rather use `\cmidrule(l){2-4}\cmidrule(l){5-7}\cmidrule(l){8-10}\cmidrule(l){11-13}`

Comment: @Zarko I agree. I would also consider grouping the twelve rows with addition space between the rows 4 and 5, and 8 and 9. But OP said equal width.

Comment: Wow, this looks much better! Now, I have to understand this all to be able to reapply. Thanks!

Comment: @Zarko, `\cmidrule(l){2-4}\cmidrule(l){5-7}\cmidrule(l){8-10}\cmidrule(l){11-13}` separate the lines which is not really what I want. Does it do anything other than separating the lines?

Answer (score 5):

How to organize table is quite opinion base. Some ones might liked the following (based on  Sveinung and my comment above):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[hb]
\centering
  \small
\caption{Results at $\mu_j=U(91,876)$ and different scenarios for $\lambda_j$.} 
\label{tab:results}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}
                                  c *{3}{*{3}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}c} 
                                    *{3}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
                             @{}}
    \toprule
    \addlinespace
    & \multicolumn{15}{c}{Planning Horizon (Years)}                 \\
\multirow{2}{*}{\makecell{Part\\ Type \#}}
    & 10& 20& 30    && 10& 20& 30   && 10& 20& 30   && 10& 20& 30   \\ 
    & \multicolumn{3}{>{\footnotesize}c}{$\lambda_j=U(0.01,0.1)$}
        && \multicolumn{3}{>{\footnotesize}c}{$\lambda_j=U(0.09,0.1)$}
            && \multicolumn{3}{>{\footnotesize}c}{$\lambda_j=U(0.1,0.5)$}
                && \multicolumn{3}{>{\footnotesize}c}{$\lambda_j=U(0.5,0.9)$}   \\
    \cmidrule(r){1-1}\cmidrule{2-4}\cmidrule{6-8}\cmidrule{10-12}\cmidrule{14-16}
1   & I & I & A     && I & A & I    && A & I & A    && A & I & A    \\
2   & I & I & A     && I & I & A    && I & I & A    && A & A & A    \\
3   & I & I & I     && I & A & A    && A & A & I    && I & I & I    \\
4   & I & I & I     && I & A & A    && I & A & I    && I & A & I    \\
5   & I & P & P     && I & I & P    && A & I & P    && P & P & A    \\
6   & I & A & A     && I & I & A    && A & I & A    && I & A & I    \\ 
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```