# Alignment of multi-column headers for pairs of columns

Tags: tables, multicolumn, column-width

So I would like to produce a table, whereby the heading of each multicolumn represents a certain distance and the sub-columns some numerical measurements associated with it.

```
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\centering                %% <-- Move outside tabular
\hrule                    %% <-- It is either \toprule or \hline

\multicolumn{2}{c}{290cm} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{190cm}\\
n & m & n & m\\
\cmidrule(lr){1-2}
\cmidrule(l){3-4}
14 & 100 & 6 & 50 \\
2 & 17 & 5 & 45\\
4 & 30 & & \\
9 & 80 & & \\
\end{tabular}
```

The problem is for some reason the "290cm" isn't aligned as a multicolumn heading, but as a heading only of the second sub-column. What's wrong?

Comment: Your example doesn't compile, even with the appropriate markup added around it.  `\hrule` can't be used there; you shouldn't use `\centering` within your `tabular` environment; and you should mention that you're using `booktabs`.  All that said, when the `\hrule` and `centering` are removed, your table appears precisely as it should, as far as I can tell, including the "290cm" being centered over its two columns.  What precisely is going wrong?

Comment: Please always post a _complete_ small document that peopel can run to debug your problem without having to guess the definition of commands used. (`\cmidrule` is not a standard command for example)

Comment: `190 cm` is wider than the combined widths of the first and second column. The multicolumn entry will therefore appear os off center with respect to the corresponding columns. See also [Table column widths disproportionate due to multicolumn cell being too long](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/95309/134144)

Comment: Yes I'm sorry; this is my very first post on this exchange forum. I will include those for future questions.

Comment: @leandriis I compiled the tabular with tablary and four C columns, the width set to 107pt (not overfull boxes) and tymin 1pt. Both tabulars was exactly the same. The off center is probably only an optical illusion because the columns have different width.

Comment: It was indeed a problem of proper compilation. Once that was solved then the alignments became proper. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For me it seems that it compiles correctly, if you move the `\centering` out of the tabular and change `\hrule` to `\toprule`. However, if you use four `c`-columns, the second column is wider than the other, and the third column is a little narrower. Therefore, the second heading (190cm) *seems* to be a little bit offset, but I think this is just an optical illusion. Maybe you should consider using four fixed width columns, as I do in the test example.

In the test example, I have set the tabular with fixed width columns (`wc{<wd>}`), to demonstrate that the alignment is correct. For the same reason, I added the vertical lines. They are there for illustration purposes and should be removed:

**Example 1 – test version**

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\centering

\begin{tabular}{*{4}{wc{1cm}|}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{290cm} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{190cm}\\
n & m & n & m\\
\cmidrule(lr){1-2}
\cmidrule(l){3-4}
14 & 100 & 6 & 50 \\
2 & 17 & 5 & 45\\
4 & 30 & & \\
9 & 80 & & \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

**Example 2 – final version A**

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\centering

%\begin{tabular}{*{4}{wc{1cm}|}}
\begin{tabular}{*{4}{c}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{290cm} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{190cm}\\
n & m & n & m\\
\cmidrule(r){1-2}
\cmidrule(l){3-4}
14 & 100 & 6 & 50 \\
2 & 17 & 5 & 45\\
4 & 30 & & \\
9 & 80 & & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

**Example 3 – final version B**

Here is a version with fixed width columns. 15 pt in minimum width before you get `Overfull hbox`es:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array, caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{A table\label{tab:a-table}}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{*{4}{Wc{15pt}}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{290cm} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{190cm}\\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{n} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{m} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{n} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{m}\\
\cmidrule(r){1-2}
\cmidrule(l){3-4}
14 & 100 & 6 & 50 \\
2   &  17  & 5 & 45\\
4   &  30  &    &     \\
9   &  80  &    &     \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use also `siunitx` for better aligning the figures.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{
  S[table-format=2.0]
  S[table-format=3.0]
  S[table-format=2.0]
  S[table-format=2.0]
}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\SI{290}{cm}} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\SI{190}{cm}} \\
\cmidrule(lr){1-2} \cmidrule(lr){3-4}
{$n$} & {$m$} & {$n$} & {$m$} \\
\midrule
14 & 100 & 6 & 50 \\
2 & 17 & 5 & 45\\
4 & 30 & & \\
9 & 80 & & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]