# Equal spacing in table columns

Tags: tables, size

How can I make the spacing of the x, y and z columns the same size. The code follows below. It also follows a picture of how it is.

Thank you for the help.

```
\begin{table}[!h]
\caption{Nível e dimensões das \emph{boxes} de refinamento utilizadas neste trabalho.}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Nível de Refinamento} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Dimensões da \emph{Box} de Refinamento {[}m{]}} \\ \cline{2-4} 
                                      & x                  & y                  & z                  \\ \hline
5                                     & 1,000              & 1,000              & 2,500              \\ \hline
6                                     & 0,750              & 0,750              & 1,250              \\ \hline
7                                     & 0,500              & 0,500              & 0,625              \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\label{tabrefinamento}
\legend{Fonte: Próprio Autor.}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  See also: [Table column widths disproportionate due to multicolumn cell being too long](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/95309/134144) Alternatively, you could allow a linebreak inside of the text in the multicolumn.

Answer (score 2):

Here are three different versions of your table:

[image]

```
\documentclass{Article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]
\caption{Nível e dimensões das \emph{boxes} de refinamento utilizadas neste trabalho.}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{c*{3}{|wc{1.75cm}}}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Nível de Refinamento} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Dimensões da \emph{Box} de Refinamento {[}m{]}} \\ \cline{2-4} 
                                      & x                  & y                  & z                  \\ \hline
5                                     & 1,000              & 1,000              & 2,500              \\ \hline
6                                     & 0,750              & 0,750              & 1,250              \\ \hline
7                                     & 0,500              & 0,500              & 0,625              \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\label{tabrefinamento}

\end{table}


\begin{table}[!h]
\caption{Nível e dimensões das \emph{boxes} de refinamento utilizadas neste trabalho.}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\makecell{Nível de\\ Refinamento}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\makecell{Dimensões da \emph{Box}\\ de Refinamento {[}m{]}}} \\ \cline{2-4} 
                                      & x                  & y                  & z                  \\ \hline
5                                     & 1,000              & 1,000              & 2,500              \\ \hline
6                                     & 0,750              & 0,750              & 1,250              \\ \hline
7                                     & 0,500              & 0,500              & 0,625              \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\label{tabrefinamento}

\end{table}

\begin{table}[!h]
\caption{Nível e dimensões das \emph{boxes} de refinamento utilizadas neste trabalho.}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\toprule
\makecell{Nível de\\ Refinamento} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\makecell{Dimensões da \emph{Box}\\ de Refinamento {[}m{]}}} \\ 
\cmidrule{2-4} 
                                      & x                  & y                  & z                  \\
\midrule 
5                                     & 1,000              & 1,000              & 2,500              \\ 
6                                     & 0,750              & 0,750              & 1,250              \\ 
7                                     & 0,500              & 0,500              & 0,625              \\ 
\midrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\label{tabrefinamento}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your attention and cordiality in answering my question. The problem was perfectly solved.

Comment: Since my answer seems to have solved your issue, please consider marking it as the [accepted answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓).