# Equal spaces on other edge columns when using multicolumn with longer contents

Tags: multicolumn, arrays

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation*}
        \begin{array}{|r|c|l|}
            \multicolumn{3}{c}{%
               AAAAAAAAAAAAA 
            }\\
            a & b & c\\
            a & b & c
        \end{array}
    \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

This code outputs this:

[image: my output]

which extends the column on the right. How can I make it so that the left column  and the right column are equally extended? (like "a|b|c" should be in the middle of "AAAAAA")

Example:

[image: expected output]

Comment: See also: [Table column widths disproportionate due to multicolumn cell being too long](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/95309/134144)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to make LaTeX perform the column width calculations. The *overall* width of the `array` is set to the argument of the `\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{...}` directive. The main point is to use a column type that takes a length parameter as an argument instead of the basic `l`, `c`, and `r` column types.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array} % for 'w' column type
\newlength{\mylen}
\settowidth\mylen{$AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA$}
\addtolength\mylen{\dimexpr-4\arraycolsep-2\arrayrulewidth\relax}
\setlength\mylen{\dimexpr\mylen/3\relax}

\newcolumntype{L}{w{l}{\mylen}}
\newcolumntype{C}{w{c}{\mylen}}
\newcolumntype{R}{w{r}{\mylen}}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{|R|C|L|}
    \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA}\\
    \hline
    a & b & c\\
    \dots & \dots & \dots \\
    a & b & c
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: If all you want to achieve is to typeset the `a|b|c` material more compactly, I suggest you pursue a nested `array` approach instead.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{array}{|c|}
    AAAAAAAAAAAAA \\ 
    \hline
    \begin{array}{r|c|l}
        a & b & c\\
        a & b & c
    \end{array}
  \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation!

Comment: One question, how should I do that without defining a fixed length?

Comment: @Toma - Please clarify what "that" refers to. Relatedly, please help me understand *why* you wouldn't want to use a fixed width. (Note that in the first half of the answer, the column width (`\mylen`) is not really fixed but is calculated dynamically.)

Comment: How can I achieve what you wrote in your answer without `\settowidth\mylen{$AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA$}`, so that it would work for any length of text in the multicolumn

Comment: @Toma - The `\settowidth\muylen{...}`, `\addtolength\mylen{...}`, and `\setlength\mylen{...}` directives don't have to occur in the preamble. They could, for instance, occur right between `\[` and `\begin{array}{|R|C|L|}`. That way, `\mylen` could be updated repeatedly throughout the document, to adapt to the width of the header line of the `array`. Does such an approach meet your typesetting needs?

Comment: So it's not possible without a fixed length? So that the array would "adapt" its contents depending on the content's width

Comment: @Toma - I'm starting to realize that I have not at all understood what you're trying to achieve. I thought that you wanted, starting from an overall width, to assure that the widths of the three individual columns were one third of the overall width. This assumption is evidently false. Do please explain what it is that you really wish to achieve. And please be patient.

Comment: I am sorry. I have updated my question

Comment: @Toma - I've taken a look at your updated question. The addendum to my answer, which suggests using a nested-array approach, would appear to cover your updated objective. Or am i (still) missing something?

Comment: It should cover the objective if I only have one set of "inner arrays", but if I have multiple, the vertical lines would not be in the same position

Comment: @Toma - So i definitely have *no idea* what's going on. Sorry. Maybe un-accept my answer?

Comment: No need to, your answer applies for most cases. What I mean is if you have multiple arrays inside the main array, and those arrays have content with various widths, the vertical lines that separate the columns will not be aligned, as they are not part of the same array