# How to make cells with the same width in a table?

Tags: tables

My question code is as follows:

```
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{a} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{bcbcbcbc} \\ \cline{2-3} 
                   & d          & e                \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

The result is as follows:

[image: figure]

I want to make d and e boxes the same width.
How can I do that?

Comment: See also: [Table column widths disproportionate due to multicolumn cell being too long](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/95309/134144)

Answer (score 8):

Here's a solution that guarantees that the width of the combined header cell -- which currently contains `bcbcbcbc`, but which presumably is usually more informative -- is *minimal*, i.e., that the whitespace padding on either edge of the combined cell is equal to `\tabcolsep`. Observe that the solution employs the `w` column type rather than the `c` column type for columns 2 and 3; the `w` column type lets you state a required width.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow,calc}

\usepackage{array} % for 'w' column type
\newlength\lenA \newlength\lenB
% Retrieve the usable width of the combined header cell:
\settowidth\lenA{bcbcbcbc} 
% Compute the usable width of the underlying columns:
\setlength\lenB{(\lenA-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth)/2} 

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{ | c *{2}{w{c}{\lenB}|} }
  \hline
  \multirow{2}{*}{a} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{bcbcbcbc} \\ 
  \cline{2-3} 
                     & d & e \\ 
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Now i see I'm getting old. it's getting harder and harder to remember the new array's   column specification options :-(. Nice answer (+1)

Answer (score 6):

This frequently asked question ... Try something like this:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tabular}{|c|*{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{3em}| }
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{a} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{bcbcbcbc} \\ \cline{2-3} 
                   & d          & e                \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image]

in preamble you should have

```
\usepackage{array, multirow}
```