# why are these table subheaders not evenly spaced

Tags: tables

Space under subheader w/ `#` and `%` are not even, why is this?

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\rowcolors{1}{}{lightgray}
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{7}{|c|}{Sample QC} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{CoreExome-24 v1.0} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{CoreExome-24 v1.0} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{CoreExome-24 v1.1}\\
\cline{2-7}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{QC Flag} & \# & \% & \# & \% & \# & \% \\
\hline
 UNUSUAL\_XY & 19 & 0.09 & 70 & 0.18 & 70 & 0.18 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: if a spanning entry is wider than the columns it spans then all the excess width goes in the last spanned column

Comment: See also: [Table column widths disproportionate due to multicolumn cell being too long](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/95309/134144)

Answer (score 1):

In the following MWE, I used `\widthof` from the `calc` package in order to measure the width of the entry in the `\multicolumn` command. I then used 6 `wc` type columns from the `array` package instead of the regular `c` type columns. I then made sure, to use half of the before determined width as the width argument of the `wc` column.

[image]

The table in the following MWE exceeds the textwidth. I decided to not address that issue, since there was no documentclass given in the original question and I just guessed one.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}


\usepackage{array} % for the w column type
\usepackage{calc} % for the \widthof command

\newlength{\mycolwidth}
\setlength{\mycolwidth}{\widthof{CoreExome-24 v1.0}}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\rowcolors{1}{}{lightgray}
\begin{tabular}{|l|*{6}{wc{0.5\mycolwidth-2\tabcolsep}|}}
\hline
\multicolumn{7}{|c|}{Sample QC} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{CoreExome-24 v1.0} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{CoreExome-24 v1.0} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{CoreExome-24 v1.1}\\
\cline{2-7}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{QC Flag} & \# & \% & \# & \% & \# & \% \\
\hline
 UNUSUAL\_XY & 19 & 0.09 & 70 & 0.18 & 70 & 0.18 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\documentclass{article}`, apologies first question here. Thank you for the help

Comment: If you want to make sure, your table fits into the textwidth of a regular `article` class document, add `\small
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5pt}` right after `\centering`. This will slightly reduce the font size as well as teh horizontal white space between an vertical line and the text in a table cell and thus allow the table to fit. With this approach you should get rid of the overfull box warning, that you get from the original code in my answer.