# How to fix uneven column when using \cline

Tags: spacing, alignment, columns

I am new to LaTeX and I am trying to create a table. I have read all the documentation about tables from Wikibooks. The problem I am having is while using \cline my column spacing is uneven.

[image: table with uneven column]

I've have the following code:

```
    %begin table 1
\begin{table*}
\centering      
\caption{Description of datasets of proficiency test results from AAFCO check sample program}

    \setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{10pt}
    \setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{-12pt}
    \setlength\extrarowheight{4pt} % sets row height
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{15pt} % sets column space
    %\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
    \vspace{6pt}
\scalebox{1.0}{
\begin{tabular}{ | c | c | c | c | c |  }

\hline

\multirow{2}{*}{Year} & \multirow{2}{*}{Feed Type} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{\# of laboratories 
submitting the PT results} & \multirow{2}{*}{\# of analyses} \\ \cline{3-4}

 &   & Min &  Max &  \\
\hline

test & test & test & test & test \\
\hline


\end{tabular}
\label{tab:tab1}
}
\end{table*}
%end table 1
```

one remedy that I have tried is using \multirow{1}{2.5cm}{Min}, but my text is not aligned. Picture is below

[image: remedy]

I am trying to recreate this table. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

[image: desired table]

Comment: It is much easier to help if you provide a test document not just a fragment but avoid doing this `\scalebox{1.0}{` scaling tables should b a non-aim, although a scale factor of 1 is just slowing things down and forcing a space at the start. I don't see any column spacing related to cline that is uneven.  can you clarify what you want to change?

Comment: Related: [Table column widths disproportionate due to multicolumn cell being too long](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/95309/134144) You may also be interested in the `hspan=even` option offered by the `tabularray` package.

Comment: oh you mean min and max, that's due to the multicolumn as leandriis just commented

Comment: @leandriis thank you! I will investigate the use hspan and the related post.

Comment: Does the fact that you're using a `table*` environment mean that your document uses a two-column layout? Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution with the `wc` column type. I  removed the `\scalebox` command, which shouldn't be used with tables, as it leads to inconsistent font sizes.

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{array, multirow}
    \usepackage{makecell}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{table*}
    \centering
    \caption{Description of datasets of proficiency test results from AAFCO check sample program}

        \setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{10pt}
        \setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{-12pt}
        \setlength\extrarowheight{4pt} % sets row height
        \setlength{\tabcolsep}{15pt} % sets column space
        \vspace{6pt}
    \begin{tabular}{ | c | c | wc{15mm} | wc{15mm} | c | }
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{Year} & \multirow{2}{*}{Feed Type} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{\makecell{\# of laboratories\\
    submitting the PT results}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\# of analyses} \\ \cline{3-4}
     & & Min & Max & \\
    \hline
    test & test & test & test & test \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \label{tab:tab1}
    \end{table*}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the edit, @Sebastiano ! : o)

Comment: Ahahahah :-) you're welcome. It is always a pleasure to help the other users.

Comment: so the wc column type sets a determined word limit, and the \makecell command is for putting contents within that cell @Bernard?

Comment: @jay0987: The wc column type is a recent column type, somewhet like p, but adds that the contents is centred; makecell allows for line breaks  in all types of cells, and its contents is centred by default, both vertically and horizontally.

Comment: @Bernard: I did not know that. I haven't seen that yet. I have only seen the column types p, m, and b for alignment. Thank you for your time and speedy reply!

Comment: @jay0987: This is explained (I mean wc and similar) in the documentation of recent versions of the array package.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution which (a) uses a `tabularx` enviroment and allows automatic line-breaking (with hanging indentation) in the second column and (b) uses fixed equal widths for columns 3, 4, and 5. It also does away with all vertical lines and uses few, but well-spaced horizontal lines.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for well-spaced horizontal rules
\usepackage{array}    % for 'w' and 'm' column types
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\hangafter=1\hangindent=1em}X}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[skip=0.5\baselineskip]{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}    
\caption{Description of datasets of proficiency test results 
         from AAFCO check sample program}
\label{tab:tab1}
\newlength\mylen
\settowidth\mylen{\# of analyses} % measure widths of cols 2 thru 5

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l L *{3}{wc{\mylen}} @{}}
\toprule
Year 
& Feed Type 
& \multicolumn{2}{ >{\centering}m{2\mylen+2\tabcolsep} }{%
  \# of laboratories submitting the PT results} 
& \# of analyses \\ 
\cmidrule(lr){3-4}
& & min & max & \\
\midrule
2022 
   & Beet pulp & 5 & 55 & 45 \\
   & Calf starter\slash grower, medicated & 6 & 209 & 58 \\
   & \dots \\
   & Ewe developer \& gestation feed, medicated & 10 & 214 & 35 \\
   & \dots \\
   & Pelleted sheep concentrate, medicated & 7 & 212 & 54 \\
   & \dots \\
   & Swine grower, medicated & 5 & 155 & 55 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you for your solution and time.